# Add and manage a layer over a canvas using SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to say that maybe (probably) the word 'layer' is not the correct one, but I believe it gives the correct idea of what I want to do.

I am using a SurfaceView which implements SurfaceHolder.Callback.

I am working on a canvas. I am drawing a quite complex set of points.
I have the canvas translated, rotated and scaled (translateX and translateY are variable that changes when the user interacts with the canvas):

```
canvas.translate(0, 0);
canvas.rotate(-90);
canvas.translate(translateX, translateY);
canvas.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
```

My next step is to add text and images on top of this canvas.
Both the text and the images should not be scaled nor rotated, only translated (they should follow the canvas).

For this reason I was thinking about having some sort of 'layer' or something similar transparent which only follows the canvas movements and does not change on zoom in or zoom out or on rotation [think them as some sort of UI which stay over the whole canvas].

**EDIT:**

Here is a snippet:

```
  @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        try{
            pt.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawText("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO", 100, 10, pt);
            pt.setAntiAlias(true);  
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(-90, 0, 0);
            canvas.drawText("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO", getHeight(), 10, pt);
            canvas.restore();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
```

I want the two 'HELLOOOOOO' to appear close to each other. I can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use save() and restore() so that after all your canvas is "normal" again. Than you can draw on it easily?

Save and restore working like a SceneGraph, if you have heard of it.

Comment: Will it work? I tried to put a text on a canvas and it was rotated. I will try to read about save() and restore(), let's see. :)

Comment: I just tried and the text does not appear (I think the issue is related to the coordinates, but I cant figure out how to solve it):               canvas.save();
              
              
              canvas.rotate(90, 0, 0);
              
              pt.setTextSize(1000);
              canvas.drawText("TEXT", x, y, pt);
              
              canvas.restore();

Comment: You should save first, than do your drawing, than restore, and than draw your text. If done so, it should be like you have never touched the canvas and the text appears on the correct coordinates...

Comment: I have done how suggested, and it makes more sense, but still; I want the text to be in the same place as the drawing. So the coordinates are different.
The correct coordinates should be (x,y) --> (-y,x) but I cannot find the text (I have the canvas centered on the drawing).

Comment: Could you provide the project? I would like to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this. I simply rotated the canvas using:

```
rotate(+90, X, Y);
```

and then rotated back

```
rotate(-90, X, Y);
```

Doing this, the (X,Y) coordinates remain the same.